# looping through json only working for first item

Tags: jquery, json, loops

Hi i am trying to loop through some json data and output it onto the page, my problem is it's only displaying the first item in the json, (boston manor car park)
i cant get it to display the second item...

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/35Jrc/6/

HTML:

```
<span class='showOnMap' 
     data-related='[
            {"id":"5","slug":"boston-manor-park-car-park","name":"Boston Manor Park car park","image":"","pinType":"ub","addr":"Boston Manor Road, London  ","lat":"51.48967509541307","lng":"-0.3164195004638941","contact":"Reel Film Locations: ","restrictions":"Shared use with park users. 6 classic 1960 Tower Blocks"},
            {"id":"4","slug":"gunnersbury-park-car-park","name":"Gunnersbury Park car park","image":"","pinType":"ub","addr":"Popes Lane, London  W3 8LQ","lat":"51.49963692687797","lng":"-0.29188622747801674","contact":"Reel Film Locations: 0845 402 2998","restrictions":"Shared use with sports ground users.  Weekends in season are busy with the public. 6 classic 1960 Tower Blocks"}
        ]'>
         click me
</span>
<div class="relatedHeader">Unit Bases near by:</div>
<div class="relatedDetails">

</div>
```

JS:

```
$('.showOnMap').click(function(){
    //alert('click');
    var myRelated = $(this).data('related');

    createRelated(myRelated)
    //addToPanel(panelData);
})     
function createRelated(myRelated){
        var relCount = 0;
        var rowCount = 0;
        var itemCount = 0;
            var relCount = 0;
        $.each(myRelated, function(k, v) {
            if(relCount == 3){
                relCount = 0;
            };
            // create a new row
            if(relCount == 0){
                var rowClass = 'relRow'+rowCount;
                //alert('new row class: .'+rowClass);
                $("<div></div>")
                .addClass("detailRow "+rowClass)
                .appendTo(".relatedDetails");
                rowCount++;
            }
            // create a new related item div
            var itemClass = 'item'+itemCount;
            //alert('new item class: .'+itemClass);
            $("<div></div>")
            .addClass("relatedItem "+itemClass)
            .appendTo('.'+rowClass);

            //$('.'+rowClass).append('.'+itemClass);
            // now loop through the keys and values and add the data
            //add the data to the related item
            $('.'+itemClass).data('location',this);
            //add item to to our row

            //$.each(obj, function(k, v) {
                  //tmp = {"id":"5","slug":"boston-manor-park-car-park","name":"Boston Manor Park car park","image":"","pinType":"ub","addr":"Boston Manor Road, London ","lat":"51.48967509541307","lng":"-0.3164195004638941","contact":"Reel Film Locations: ","restrictions":"Shared use with park users. External features unavaliable at present"};
                //if(k=='image'){
                    $('<img/>')
                    .addClass('relatedImage')
                    .attr("src", v.image)
                    .appendTo('.'+itemClass)
                //}
                //if(k=='name'){
                    $('<div></div>')
                    .addClass('relatedTitle')
                    .html(v.name)
                    .appendTo('.'+itemClass)
                //}
            //});
            itemCount++;
            relCount++;
        });
    };
```

Comment: Your `var rowClass` is local to each iteration of the loop.  It's only set when `relCount` is 0, otherwise it's undefined.

Comment: thanks i put have defined 'relCount' outside the main loop now though still does not display the second item in my json...

Comment: Are you updating the value of `rowClass` when you need to?  Because I moved the `var rowClass` before the `$.each`, and I see 2 items: http://jsfiddle.net/35Jrc/7/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in line 32 of your fiddle:

`.appendTo('.'+rowClass);`

Check what `rowClass` equals in each iteration of your `$.each` loop. It's only defined the first time, when this conditional is met:

```
if(relCount == 0){
    var rowClass = 'relRow'+rowCount;
}
```

You should change the way you're storing the row that you add your item to. (Changes on lines 17 and 30.)

```
$('.showOnMap').click(function(){
    var myRelated = $(this).data('related');

    createRelated(myRelated);
});


function createRelated(myRelated){

    // Clear any previous content
    $('.relatedDetails').html('');

    var relCount = 0;
    var rowCount = 0;
    var itemCount = 0;
    var relCount = 0;

    // Store a reference to the current row
    var row = '';

    console.log('myRelated', myRelated);
    $.each(myRelated, function(k, v) {
        console.log('k, v', k, v);
        console.log('relCount', relCount);
        if (relCount == 3) {
            relCount = 0;
        };
        // create a new row
        if(relCount == 0){
            rowClass = 'relRow'+rowCount;

            // Save the row you're creating
            row = $("<div></div>")
            .addClass("detailRow "+rowClass)
            .appendTo(".relatedDetails");
            rowCount++;
        }
        // create a new related item div
        var itemClass = 'item'+itemCount;
        //alert('new item class: .'+itemClass);
        var newItem = $("<div></div>")
        .addClass("relatedItem "+itemClass)
        .appendTo(row);

        //$('.'+rowClass).append('.'+itemClass);
        // now loop through the keys and values and add the data
        //add the data to the related item
        newItem.data('location',this);
        //add item to to our row



        //if(k=='image'){
        $('<img/>')
        .addClass('relatedImage')
        .attr("src", v.image)
        .appendTo('.'+itemClass)
        //}
        //if(k=='name'){
        $('<div></div>')
        .addClass('relatedTitle')
        .html(v.name)
        .appendTo('.'+itemClass)
        //}

        itemCount++;
        relCount++;
    });
};
```

You can see it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/cYavP/1/

Comment: so annoying when ur going thru code only to have someone beat u to the answer haha. good catch.

Comment: I know exactly what you mean!

Comment: ahh ok i see that makes a lot of sense now you have pointed it out!! while i was looking around i saw jQuery 1.9 hasa new Unique ID function, i will look at that in more depth also, as once i have gone through 3 rows, i will be duplicating id's (though i dont think i will have 9 related items, but best to cos for it just in case.

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#added-uniqueid-and-removeuniqueid-methods here the link for the new uniqueID function in 1.9